# Android SDK components are not getting downloaded

Tags: android, android-studio

While installing Android Studio , a dialog box came showing that 'Finding available SDK Components' it shows up for a minute and the bar doesn't moves a bit and cancels to bring up a new dialog box saying "Missing SDK",No Android SDK found.
PLEASE HELP I'M STUCK

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run Android Studio as an administrator, by right-clicking on the .exe and selecting "Run As Administrator".

Comment: Tried doing that but  the same problem continues.

Comment: So you can't even start android studio now? If you can start it, you should check the SDK path.

Comment: Yes I am not able to start it , when I click "Start a New Project "or anything on the window it says Android SDK missing .

Comment: Click on "Configure" > "SDK Manager" and check the path.

Comment: Sorry but even the Path is not showing . It is asking me set the Android SDK path.

Comment: You can click on "Edit", it will give you the option to install it in certain location.

Comment: In the Android Studio Installation dialog box ?

Comment: No if you click on "Configure" > "SDK Manager" you can see the empty path. Besides this path you should see an "Edit" button. When you click on that button you can install the SDK in a certain location.

Comment: With no other choice I had to switch from my laptop to Desktop and that worked fine in just first attempt without any errors. Now I can use Android Studio with charm!